# OpenGL 4 - Euler rotations not making any sense

Tags: c#

I am messing around with modern OpenGL in C#, and I am trying to rotate a quad so that it is 90 degrees on the X axis. The problem is, the product of the rotation makes no sense. Instead of being turned sideways, it flips itself only around half way. Also, changing the degrees only by one (90 to 91), completely changes the outcome. 
My euler order is: **Y, X, Z**.

**Rotation Matrix**

```
internal Matrix4 rotx;
internal Matrix4 roty;
internal Matrix4 rotz;
internal float sin;
internal float cos;

public Matrix4 CreateRotationMatrix(float anglex, float angley, float anglez)
{
//X
cos = (float)Math.Cos(anglex);
sin = (float)Math.Sin(anglex);
rotx = new Matrix4(new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, cos, sin, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, -sin, cos, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

//Y
cos = (float)Math.Cos(angley);
sin = (float)Math.Sin(angley);

roty = new Matrix4(new Vector4(cos, 0.0f, -sin, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector4(sin, 0.0f, cos, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

//Z
cos = (float)Math.Cos(anglez);
sin = (float)Math.Sin(anglez);

roty = new Matrix4(new Vector4(cos, sin, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector4(-sin, cos, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

return (roty * rotx) * rotz;
}
```

I then put it into a model matrix, with the order: **scale, translate, rotate**.

What have I done wrong?

**Product of 90 degree X axis rotation**[image] 
**Product of 90 degree Y axis rotation**[image]
**Product of 90 degree Z axis rotation**[image]

Comment: Did you forget to convert degrees into radians?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! If you make an answer for it, I will make it the accepted answer. Thanks! That was 2 hours wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trig functions in `System.Math` measure all angles in radians (both for inputs and in the case of inverse "arc"-functions return values).

If you are designing in degrees, you'll have to remember to convert angles to radians before calling the library functions.